# Django aggregation taking a lot of time

Tags: python, django

I have a model defined as bellow

```
class Image(model.Models):
    # Stages
    STAGE_TRAIN = 'train'
    STAGE_VAL = 'val'
    STAGE_TEST = 'test'
    STAGE_TRASH = 'trash'

    STAGE_CHOICES = (
        (STAGE_TRAIN, 'Train'),
        (STAGE_VAL, 'Validation'),
        (STAGE_TEST, 'Test'),
        (STAGE_TRASH, 'Trash'),
    )
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STAGE_CHOICES, default=STAGE_TRAIN)
    commit = models.ForeignKey(Commit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images", related_query_name="image")
```

In my database I have 170k images and I try to have an endpoint that will count all the images by stage

Currently I have something like that

```
base_query = Image.objects.filter(commit=commit_uuid).only('id', 'stage')
count_query = base_query.aggregate(count_train=Count('id', filter=Q(stage='train')),
                                   count_val=Count('id', filter=Q(stage='val')),
                                   count_trash=Count('id', filter=Q(stage='trash')))
```

but it takes around 40sec and when I try to see the SQL request in my shell I have something that looks ok

```
{'sql': 'SELECT COUNT("image"."id") FILTER (WHERE "image"."stage" = \'train\') AS "count_train", COUNT("image"."id") FILTER (WHERE "image"."stage" = \'val\') AS "count_val", COUNT("image"."id") FILTER (WHERE "image"."stage" = \'trash\') AS "count_trash" FROM "image" WHERE "image"."commit_id" = \'333681ff-886a-42d0-b88a-5d38f1e9fe94\'::uuid', 'time': '42.140'}
```

an other strange thing is that if I change my aggregate function with

```
count_query = base_query.aggregate(count_train=Count('id', filter=Q(stage='train')&Q(commit=commit_uuid)),
                                           count_val=Count('id', filter=Q(stage='val')&Q(commit=commit_uuid)),
                                           count_trash=Count('id', filter=Q(stage='trash')&Q(commit=commit_uuid)))
```

When I do that the query is twice as fast (still 20sec) and when I display the SQL I see that the filter on the commit is done inside the `FILTER`

So I have two questions:

- Can I do something different to improve the speed of the query or should I store the count somewhere and change the values each time I change an image ?
- I was expecting the query to filter first on the commit id and then on the `stage` but I have the feeling that it's done the otherway around

Comment: I would first add some indexes on the `stage`, this should boost performance probably a lot more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can add the fields indices either with `index_together` option

```
class Image(model.Models):
    class Meta:
         index_together = [['stage'], ['stage', 'commit']]
```

or the `indexes` option (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes)

```
class Image(model.Models):
    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['stage', 'commit'])]
```

2) You don't need the necessity to look up the `id`:

```
base_query = Image.objects.filter(commit=commit_uuid).only('stage')

# count images in stages
count = base_query.aggregate(train=Count(1, filter=Q(commit=commit_uuid) & Q(stage='train')),
                             val=Count(1, filter=Q(commit=commit_uuid) & Q(stage='val')),
                             trash=Count(1, filter=Q(commit=commit_uuid) & Q(stage='trash')))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this in your model:

`stage = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STAGE_CHOICES, default=STAGE_TRAIN, index=True)`

By adding an index to stage, you should avoid full table scans.